# Get href of an anchor inside <h3> tags

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is the html,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3 class="abc">
<a href="abc.html">link1</a>
</h3>
<h2 class="abc">
<a href="xyz.html">link1</a>
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a php regex or anything else, to get href of anchor e.g. "abc.html" which is inside only h3 tags NOT h2 tags.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do You will manipulate a html file?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML.  Use an XML/HTML parser instead.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @ViniciusMonteiro No, it will be a html string passed by ajax post method every time.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using `DOMDocument`, which is a real HTML parser. I haven't tested this, but this is probably the approach you should take:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$h3s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');

$anchors = array();
foreach($h3s as $h3){
   $links = $h3->getElementsByTagName('a');
   foreach($links as $link){
      $anchors[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
   }
}
print_r($anchors); //should have all of your `href`s
```

In general, try not to use Regex to parse HTML... and [read up on DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Didn't quite worked. But i got the idea, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use JQuery, you could use

```
<script>
  $("h3 a").attr("href");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
#<h3[^>]+>\s+<a\s+href="([^"]+)">.+?</a>\s+</h3>#
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/xK4pT3

Comment: Didn't worked for me :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @AliNawazHiraj I have updated my answer, please check also the demo

Comment: @Greg I'm aware of the (silly imho) idea of using regex on HTML is bad ! :)

Comment: If you're aware, why did you answer with a regular expression? It's not always going to work. This question is the classic [x-y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @xyProblem in some simple cases, regex gives less code